# Styling Angular Material DatePicker

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to Style my Material Design DatePicker component for Angular. We managed this by overriding css classes. This is from my understood wrong as recommend is to use custom themes. The problem is Material Design is very poor documented about styling. They also don't mention, that the usage of custom colours is not allowed.

We also want to set the size of the DatePicker and it seems to be impossible only by setting the `width`.

Is there any proper article / guide / documentation of how to style Material Design components properly?